# Neovim + galaxyline plugin crushing

Tags: neovim, vim-airline, statusline

When i press alt+tab and nvim folding galaxyline plugin crushing and airline default theme appears,but when i saving file galaxyline is start working

galaxy line is working
[image: galaxy line is working]

I press alt+tab and galaxyline is crushing
[image: i press alt+tab and galaxyline is crushing]

saving file in vim and galaxyline is working
[image: saving file in vim and galaxyline is working]
P.S i dont have installed airline